# How to display the receipt number(s) and its total price for the receipt(s) that contain 'Twist' as one among five items?

Tags: mysql, sql, having

Question: Display the receipt number(s) and its total price for the receipt(s) that contain Twist as one among five items. Include only the receipts with a total price of more than $25.

My attempt:

```
SELECT r.receipt_number, 
       p.price
       SUM(p.price) AS total_price
FROM item_list i
LEFT JOIN receipts r
    ON r.receipt_number = i.receipt
LEFT JOIN customers c
    ON c.id = r.customer_id
LEFT JOIN products p
    ON i.item = p.id
GROUP BY food
HAVING food = 'Twist' AND price > 25;
```

The above code is giving me an error. "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SUM(p.price) AS total_price FROM item_list i LEFT JOIN receipts r ON r.recei' at line 3" I don't know how to proceed from here. I am stuck.

This is the SQL code for creating the whole database.

bakery.sql

```
CREATE DATABASE bakery;
USE bakery;

CREATE TABLE customers (
   id INT PRIMARY KEY,
   last_name VARCHAR(255),
   first_name VARCHAR(255)
);

CREATE TABLE receipts (
   receipt_number INT PRIMARY KEY,
   date DATE,
   customer_id INT,
   FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES customers (id)
);

CREATE TABLE products
 (
   id VARCHAR(255) PRIMARY KEY,
   flavor VARCHAR(255),
   food VARCHAR(255),
   price DECIMAL(7, 2)
);

CREATE TABLE item_list (
   receipt INT,
   ordinal INT,
   item VARCHAR(255),
   FOREIGN KEY (item) REFERENCES products (ID),
   FOREIGN KEY (receipt) REFERENCES receipts (receipt_number),
   PRIMARY KEY (receipt, ordinal, item)
);

INSERT INTO customers
VALUES
   (1,'LOGAN','JULIET'),
   (2,'ARZT','TERRELL'),
   (3,'ESPOSITA','TRAVIS'),
   (4,'ENGLEY','SIXTA'),
   (5,'DUNLOW','OSVALDO'),
   (6,'SLINGLAND','JOSETTE'),
   (7,'TOUSSAND','SHARRON'),
   (8,'HELING','RUPERT'),
   (9,'HAFFERKAMP','CUC'),
   (10,'DUKELOW','CORETTA'),
   (11,'STADICK','MIGDALIA'),
   (12,'MCMAHAN','MELLIE'),
   (13,'ARNN','KIP'),
   (14,'SOPKO','RAYFORD'),
   (15,'CALLENDAR','DAVID'),
   (16,'CRUZEN','ARIANE'),
   (17,'MESDAQ','CHARLENE'),
   (18,'DOMKOWSKI','ALMETA'),
   (19,'STENZ','NATACHA'),
   (20,'ZEME','STEPHEN');

INSERT INTO receipts
VALUES
   (18129,'2007-10-28',15),
   (51991,'2007-10-17',14),
   (83085,'2007-10-12',7),
   (70723,'2007-10-28',20),
   (13355,'2007-10-19',7),
   (52761,'2007-10-27',8),
   (99002,'2007-10-13',20),
   (58770,'2007-10-22',18),
   (84665,'2007-10-10',6),
   (55944,'2007-10-16',19),
   (42166,'2007-10-14',8),
   (16034,'2007-10-10',4),
   (25906,'2007-10-29',15),
   (27741,'2007-10-25',8),
   (64451,'2007-10-10',11),
   (41028,'2007-10-6',17),
   (73716,'2007-10-29',18),
   (76667,'2007-10-14',15),
   (21040,'2007-10-3',6),
   (48332,'2007-10-15',20),
   (35011,'2007-10-10',20),
   (95962,'2007-10-26',8),
   (44798,'2007-10-4',16),
   (60270,'2007-10-31',11),
   (21162,'2007-10-4',8),
   (77406,'2007-10-9',13),
   (32565,'2007-10-24',14),
   (36343,'2007-10-31',19),
   (96619,'2007-10-7',18),
   (86678,'2007-10-24',3),
   (44330,'2007-10-20',18),
   (91937,'2007-10-21',12),
   (21545,'2007-10-22',12),
   (29226,'2007-10-26',14),
   (25121,'2007-10-20',18),
   (54935,'2007-10-16',14),
   (36423,'2007-10-24',16),
   (83437,'2007-10-15',8),
   (49854,'2007-10-12',2),
   (99994,'2007-10-21',6),
   (21622,'2007-10-10',7),
   (64861,'2007-10-15',10),
   (33456,'2007-10-5',16),
   (75468,'2007-10-21',10),
   (56365,'2007-10-14',12),
   (91192,'2007-10-10',5),
   (82056,'2007-10-7',18),
   (27192,'2007-10-28',9),
   (59716,'2007-10-30',2),
   (82795,'2007-10-8',15),
   (26240,'2007-10-7',16),
   (56724,'2007-10-9',13),
   (70796,'2007-10-31',12),
   (37636,'2007-10-20',1),
   (63998,'2007-10-13',20),
   (48981,'2007-10-24',20),
   (66704,'2007-10-29',14),
   (12698,'2007-10-23',19),
   (79287,'2007-10-30',8),
   (55690,'2007-10-15',19),
   (94371,'2007-10-22',8),
   (26148,'2007-10-19',20),
   (11923,'2007-10-9',15),
   (46598,'2007-10-3',14),
   (76951,'2007-10-27',14),
   (85858,'2007-10-31',1),
   (85881,'2007-10-13',1),
   (89937,'2007-10-20',7),
   (66227,'2007-10-10',1),
   (60240,'2007-10-17',17),
   (86085,'2007-10-16',1),
   (67314,'2007-10-23',6),
   (10013,'2007-10-17',15),
   (26741,'2007-10-24',7),
   (38157,'2007-10-23',16),
   (45873,'2007-10-5',13),
   (37540,'2007-10-3',20),
   (11891,'2007-10-30',7),
   (61797,'2007-10-30',8),
   (52369,'2007-10-15',5),
   (96430,'2007-10-4',18),
   (64301,'2007-10-12',14),
   (45976,'2007-10-3',10),
   (39605,'2007-10-12',12),
   (52013,'2007-10-5',13),
   (88626,'2007-10-25',17),
   (53376,'2007-10-30',8),
   (15584,'2007-10-13',3),
   (73437,'2007-10-1',6),
   (24200,'2007-10-16',9),
   (92252,'2007-10-25',7),
   (39685,'2007-10-28',1),
   (61378,'2007-10-8',11),
   (96761,'2007-10-14',20),
   (26198,'2007-10-12',11),
   (78179,'2007-10-24',14),
   (68890,'2007-10-27',7),
   (75526,'2007-10-22',18),
   (86162,'2007-10-10',16),
   (13496,'2007-10-30',11),
   (60469,'2007-10-20',4),
   (50660,'2007-10-18',9),
   (64553,'2007-10-8',17),
   (57784,'2007-10-15',7),
   (84258,'2007-10-22',2),
   (68199,'2007-10-4',9),
   (78187,'2007-10-17',14),
   (81517,'2007-10-10',1),
   (18951,'2007-10-14',20),
   (20411,'2007-10-8',7),
   (55494,'2007-10-20',15),
   (42162,'2007-10-16',7),
   (49977,'2007-10-18',3),
   (89638,'2007-10-7',4),
   (73438,'2007-10-18',10),
   (96258,'2007-10-12',8),
   (19258,'2007-10-25',5),
   (12800,'2007-10-22',11),
   (81368,'2007-10-17',19),
   (70655,'2007-10-6',2),
   (19002,'2007-10-19',6),
   (31874,'2007-10-13',2),
   (72207,'2007-10-15',1),
   (65091,'2007-10-9',17),
   (42833,'2007-10-22',3),
   (72949,'2007-10-2',6),
   (46248,'2007-10-12',11),
   (38849,'2007-10-25',1),
   (86861,'2007-10-26',9),
   (32701,'2007-10-19',16),
   (89182,'2007-10-29',5),
   (68753,'2007-10-11',5),
   (39217,'2007-10-19',20),
   (96531,'2007-10-12',8),
   (53922,'2007-10-13',2),
   (64477,'2007-10-16',6),
   (99058,'2007-10-3',14),
   (77032,'2007-10-28',14),
   (15286,'2007-10-11',6),
   (59774,'2007-10-2',16),
   (35073,'2007-10-23',5),
   (34910,'2007-10-7',20),
   (17685,'2007-10-2',12),
   (45062,'2007-10-23',1),
   (39109,'2007-10-2',16),
   (37063,'2007-10-22',14),
   (18567,'2007-10-13',7),
   (37586,'2007-10-3',8),
   (62707,'2007-10-7',8),
   (28117,'2007-10-9',5),
   (64574,'2007-10-2',6),
   (40305,'2007-10-25',8),
   (33060,'2007-10-29',20),
   (12396,'2007-10-10',10),
   (43103,'2007-10-7',4),
   (39575,'2007-10-20',20),
   (70162,'2007-10-9',19),
   (23034,'2007-10-15',17),
   (79296,'2007-10-3',19),
   (74741,'2007-10-12',20),
   (98806,'2007-10-15',17),
   (43752,'2007-10-5',5),
   (47353,'2007-10-12',6),
   (39829,'2007-10-31',3),
   (87454,'2007-10-21',6),
   (76663,'2007-10-4',10),
   (85492,'2007-10-20',12),
   (48647,'2007-10-9',3),
   (61008,'2007-10-9',14),
   (96402,'2007-10-4',6),
   (35904,'2007-10-21',10),
   (49845,'2007-10-31',20),
   (46014,'2007-10-16',15),
   (46876,'2007-10-6',13),
   (34579,'2007-10-8',7),
   (17729,'2007-10-16',16),
   (74952,'2007-10-16',5),
   (61948,'2007-10-4',5),
   (41064,'2007-10-25',16),
   (17947,'2007-10-27',7),
   (20913,'2007-10-7',8),
   (95514,'2007-10-9',10),
   (24829,'2007-10-7',15),
   (44590,'2007-10-12',1),
   (65165,'2007-10-4',4),
   (89588,'2007-10-9',7),
   (53240,'2007-10-3',14),
   (46674,'2007-10-29',15),
   (67946,'2007-10-18',7),
   (31233,'2007-10-20',13),
   (15904,'2007-10-6',13),
   (17488,'2007-10-20',6),
   (97097,'2007-10-23',9),
   (50512,'2007-10-27',8),
   (11548,'2007-10-21',13),
   (29908,'2007-10-14',13),
   (20127,'2007-10-7',15),
   (41963,'2007-10-29',8),
   (16532,'2007-10-21',4),
   (34378,'2007-10-23',6);

INSERT INTO products
VALUES
   ('20-BC-C-10','Chocolate','Cake',8.95),
   ('20-BC-L-10','Lemon','Cake',8.95),
   ('20-CA-7.5','Casino','Cake',15.95),
   ('24-8x10','Opera','Cake',15.95),
   ('25-STR-9','Strawberry','Cake',11.95),
   ('26-8x10','Truffle','Cake',15.95),
   ('45-CH','Chocolate','Eclair',3.25),
   ('45-CO','Coffee','Eclair',3.5),
   ('45-VA','Vanilla','Eclair',3.25),
   ('46-11','Napoleon','Cake',13.49),
   ('90-ALM-I','Almond','Tart',3.75),
   ('90-APIE-10','Apple','Pie',5.25),
   ('90-APP-11','Apple','Tart',3.25),
   ('90-APR-PF','Apricot','Tart',3.25),
   ('90-BER-11','Berry','Tart',3.25),
   ('90-BLK-PF','Blackberry','Tart',3.25),
   ('90-BLU-11','Blueberry','Tart',3.25),
   ('90-CH-PF','Chocolate','Tart',3.75),
   ('90-CHR-11','Cherry','Tart',3.25),
   ('90-LEM-11','Lemon','Tart',3.25),
   ('90-PEC-11','Pecan','Tart',3.75),
   ('70-GA','Ganache','Cookie',1.15),
   ('70-GON','Gongolais','Cookie',1.15),
   ('70-R','Raspberry','Cookie',1.09),
   ('70-LEM','Lemon','Cookie',0.79),
   ('70-M-CH-DZ','Chocolate','Meringue',1.25),
   ('70-M-VA-SM-DZ','Vanilla','Meringue',1.15),
   ('70-MAR','Marzipan','Cookie',1.25),
   ('70-TU','Tuile','Cookie',1.25),
   ('70-W','Walnut','Cookie',0.79),
   ('50-ALM','Almond','Croissant',1.45),
   ('50-APP','Apple','Croissant',1.45),
   ('50-APR','Apricot','Croissant',1.45),
   ('50-CHS','Cheese','Croissant',1.75),
   ('50-CH','Chocolate','Croissant',1.75),
   ('51-APR','Apricot','Danish',1.15),
   ('51-APP','Apple','Danish',1.15),
   ('51-ATW','Almond','Twist',1.15),
   ('51-BC','Almond','Bear Claw',1.95),
   ('51-BLU','Blueberry','Danish',1.15);

INSERT INTO item_list
VALUES
   (18129,1,'70-TU'),
   (51991,1,'90-APIE-10'),
   (51991,2,'90-CH-PF'),
   (51991,3,'90-APP-11'),
   (51991,4,'26-8x10'),
   (83085,1,'25-STR-9'),
   (83085,2,'24-8x10'),
   (83085,3,'90-APR-PF'),
   (83085,4,'51-ATW'),
   (83085,5,'26-8x10'),
   (70723,1,'45-CO'),
   (13355,1,'24-8x10'),
   (13355,2,'70-LEM'),
   (13355,3,'46-11'),
   (52761,1,'90-ALM-I'),
   (52761,2,'26-8x10'),
   (52761,3,'50-CHS'),
   (52761,4,'90-BLK-PF'),
   (52761,5,'90-ALM-I'),
   (99002,1,'50-CHS'),
   (99002,2,'45-VA'),
   (58770,1,'50-CHS'),
   (58770,2,'46-11'),
   (58770,3,'45-CH'),
   (58770,4,'20-CA-7.5'),
   (84665,1,'90-BER-11'),
   (55944,1,'20-CA-7.5'),
   (55944,2,'90-LEM-11'),
   (55944,3,'70-R'),
   (55944,4,'70-R'),
   (55944,5,'50-CHS'),
   (42166,1,'70-M-VA-SM-DZ'),
   (16034,1,'46-11'),
   (16034,2,'26-8x10'),
   (16034,3,'45-CH'),
   (16034,4,'70-R'),
   (16034,5,'46-11'),
   (25906,1,'25-STR-9'),
   (27741,1,'90-BLK-PF'),
   (27741,2,'51-BC'),
   (27741,3,'90-APR-PF'),
   (64451,1,'90-BER-11'),
   (64451,2,'51-BC'),
   (64451,3,'24-8x10'),
   (64451,4,'90-BLK-PF'),
   (41028,1,'90-BER-11'),
   (73716,1,'90-PEC-11'),
   (73716,2,'90-ALM-I'),
   (73716,3,'70-LEM'),
   (73716,4,'50-CH'),
   (76667,1,'70-GON'),
   (76667,2,'90-LEM-11'),
   (21040,1,'70-R'),
   (21040,2,'20-BC-L-10'),
   (21040,3,'90-CH-PF'),
   (48332,1,'70-GA'),
   (48332,2,'70-R'),
   (35011,1,'50-CHS'),
   (95962,1,'90-APR-PF'),
   (95962,2,'90-CHR-11'),
   (95962,3,'50-CH'),
   (95962,4,'45-VA'),
   (44798,1,'90-APR-PF'),
   (44798,2,'90-CH-PF'),
   (44798,3,'90-APIE-10'),
   (44798,4,'90-APP-11'),
   (44798,5,'25-STR-9'),
   (60270,1,'20-BC-L-10'),
   (60270,2,'90-BLU-11'),
   (21162,1,'90-APP-11'),
   (21162,2,'70-TU'),
   (21162,3,'90-APR-PF'),
   (77406,1,'51-ATW'),
   (77406,2,'90-BLK-PF'),
   (77406,3,'50-APR'),
   (77406,4,'50-APR'),
   (77406,5,'24-8x10'),
   (32565,1,'50-APP'),
   (32565,2,'50-APP'),
   (32565,3,'45-VA'),
   (36343,1,'51-BC'),
   (36343,2,'51-BC'),
   (36343,3,'70-M-VA-SM-DZ'),
   (36343,4,'50-ALM'),
   (96619,1,'90-BLK-PF'),
   (86678,1,'70-M-VA-SM-DZ'),
   (86678,2,'90-LEM-11'),
   (44330,1,'70-R'),
   (44330,2,'90-BLU-11'),
   (91937,1,'51-BC'),
   (91937,2,'51-APR'),
   (21545,1,'90-BER-11'),
   (21545,2,'70-GA'),
   (21545,3,'50-ALM'),
   (21545,4,'90-BER-11'),
   (21545,5,'45-VA'),
   (29226,1,'90-PEC-11'),
   (29226,2,'90-APIE-10'),
   (29226,3,'51-BC'),
   (29226,4,'70-W'),
   (29226,5,'50-ALM'),
   (25121,1,'50-CHS'),
   (25121,2,'90-BER-11'),
   (25121,3,'45-CH'),
   (54935,1,'70-R'),
   (54935,2,'45-CH'),
   (36423,1,'45-VA'),
   (83437,1,'90-LEM-11'),
   (83437,2,'51-APR'),
   (49854,1,'90-BER-11'),
   (49854,2,'90-APP-11'),
   (99994,1,'25-STR-9'),
   (99994,2,'26-8x10'),
   (99994,3,'90-PEC-11'),
   (99994,4,'50-CH'),
   (21622,1,'45-CO'),
   (64861,1,'50-ALM'),
   (64861,2,'46-11'),
   (33456,1,'46-11'),
   (33456,2,'90-BLK-PF'),
   (75468,1,'70-M-CH-DZ'),
   (75468,2,'70-M-CH-DZ'),
   (75468,3,'90-CHR-11'),
   (56365,1,'50-APR'),
   (91192,1,'51-APP'),
   (91192,2,'51-ATW'),
   (91192,3,'50-APP'),
   (82056,1,'90-APP-11'),
   (82056,2,'50-CH'),
   (82056,3,'90-BLK-PF'),
   (82056,4,'45-CO'),
   (27192,1,'70-R'),
   (27192,2,'90-BLU-11'),
   (27192,3,'70-TU'),
   (59716,1,'51-APR'),
   (59716,2,'70-MAR'),
   (59716,3,'90-BLU-11'),
   (59716,4,'45-CO'),
   (59716,5,'90-APP-11'),
   (82795,1,'90-APR-PF'),
   (26240,1,'20-CA-7.5'),
   (56724,1,'70-M-VA-SM-DZ'),
   (70796,1,'45-CO'),
   (70796,2,'20-BC-L-10'),
   (70796,3,'45-CH'),
   (70796,4,'90-BLU-11'),
   (37636,1,'90-APR-PF'),
   (37636,2,'90-CH-PF'),
   (37636,3,'24-8x10'),
   (63998,1,'70-M-VA-SM-DZ'),
   (48981,1,'90-CHR-11'),
   (48981,2,'50-CHS'),
   (66704,1,'90-BER-11'),
   (66704,2,'51-APR'),
   (66704,3,'70-LEM'),
   (12698,1,'51-APP'),
   (12698,2,'70-R'),
   (12698,3,'26-8x10'),
   (79287,1,'90-PEC-11'),
   (79287,2,'45-VA'),
   (79287,3,'90-LEM-11'),
   (79287,4,'90-APP-11'),
   (79287,5,'51-BLU'),
   (55690,1,'70-M-CH-DZ'),
   (55690,2,'51-BLU'),
   (55690,3,'90-APP-11'),
   (94371,1,'51-BLU'),
   (26148,1,'20-CA-7.5'),
   (26148,2,'90-BLU-11'),
   (26148,3,'51-BLU'),
   (26148,4,'70-M-CH-DZ'),
   (11923,1,'70-LEM'),
   (46598,1,'70-R'),
   (46598,2,'70-W'),
   (46598,3,'70-R'),
   (76951,1,'51-BLU'),
   (85858,1,'20-CA-7.5'),
   (85858,2,'70-M-VA-SM-DZ'),
   (85858,3,'51-BLU'),
   (85881,1,'90-APP-11'),
   (89937,1,'51-BLU'),
   (89937,2,'51-BC'),
   (89937,3,'90-BER-11'),
   (89937,4,'70-R'),
   (66227,1,'90-APP-11'),
   (66227,2,'90-APIE-10'),
   (66227,3,'70-MAR'),
   (66227,4,'90-BLK-PF'),
   (60240,1,'90-APP-11'),
   (60240,2,'50-ALM'),
   (86085,1,'50-APR'),
   (86085,2,'50-APP'),
   (86085,3,'90-APR-PF'),
   (86085,4,'51-ATW'),
   (67314,1,'51-BC'),
   (67314,2,'50-CHS'),
   (67314,3,'70-TU'),
   (67314,4,'20-CA-7.5'),
   (10013,1,'70-M-CH-DZ'),
   (26741,1,'70-GA'),
   (26741,2,'50-APP'),
   (38157,1,'70-MAR'),
   (38157,2,'90-CHR-11'),
   (38157,3,'70-LEM'),
   (38157,4,'90-CHR-11'),
   (45873,1,'70-M-VA-SM-DZ'),
   (37540,1,'45-CO'),
   (37540,2,'51-APR'),
   (11891,1,'45-CO'),
   (11891,2,'50-APR'),
   (11891,3,'46-11'),
   (61797,1,'70-GON'),
   (61797,2,'90-CH-PF'),
   (61797,3,'70-M-VA-SM-DZ'),
   (61797,4,'70-M-CH-DZ'),
   (61797,5,'90-BER-11'),
   (52369,1,'90-CHR-11'),
   (52369,2,'70-TU'),
   (96430,1,'90-PEC-11'),
   (64301,1,'70-W'),
   (64301,2,'51-APR'),
   (64301,3,'90-BER-11'),
   (45976,1,'24-8x10'),
   (45976,2,'51-BC'),
   (39605,1,'90-BER-11'),
   (52013,1,'70-W'),
   (52013,2,'50-ALM'),
   (52013,3,'90-ALM-I'),
   (52013,4,'90-APP-11'),
   (88626,1,'90-APP-11'),
   (53376,1,'51-APR'),
   (53376,2,'90-CHR-11'),
   (53376,3,'90-APIE-10'),
   (53376,4,'46-11'),
   (53376,5,'90-BLU-11'),
   (15584,1,'70-LEM'),
   (73437,1,'70-M-CH-DZ'),
   (24200,1,'50-CHS'),
   (92252,1,'70-GON'),
   (92252,2,'51-ATW'),
   (92252,3,'51-BLU'),
   (92252,4,'45-VA'),
   (92252,5,'70-M-VA-SM-DZ'),
   (39685,1,'50-APP'),
   (39685,2,'70-M-CH-DZ'),
   (39685,3,'90-APR-PF'),
   (39685,4,'90-APIE-10'),
   (61378,1,'51-APR'),
   (61378,2,'90-BLK-PF'),
   (96761,1,'26-8x10'),
   (96761,2,'70-LEM'),
   (96761,3,'50-CHS'),
   (96761,4,'50-CHS'),
   (26198,1,'70-GA'),
   (26198,2,'70-GON'),
   (26198,3,'50-APP'),
   (26198,4,'20-BC-L-10'),
   (26198,5,'70-R'),
   (78179,1,'51-BLU'),
   (78179,2,'50-CHS'),
   (78179,3,'90-BLK-PF'),
   (78179,4,'45-CO'),
   (78179,5,'70-R'),
   (68890,1,'50-ALM'),
   (75526,1,'90-LEM-11'),
   (86162,1,'51-BLU'),
   (86162,2,'50-ALM'),
   (86162,3,'50-CHS'),
   (86162,4,'70-TU'),
   (86162,5,'50-ALM'),
   (13496,1,'70-W'),
   (13496,2,'90-ALM-I'),
   (13496,3,'51-ATW'),
   (13496,4,'50-APP'),
   (60469,1,'51-APR'),
   (50660,1,'70-TU'),
   (50660,2,'90-APIE-10'),
   (64553,1,'51-BC'),
   (64553,2,'90-APP-11'),
   (64553,3,'70-LEM'),
   (64553,4,'90-APP-11'),
   (57784,1,'90-CH-PF'),
   (84258,1,'51-APP'),
   (84258,2,'51-BC'),
   (68199,1,'51-APR'),
   (68199,2,'24-8x10'),
   (78187,1,'51-ATW'),
   (78187,2,'51-ATW'),
   (81517,1,'70-M-CH-DZ'),
   (81517,2,'51-ATW'),
   (18951,1,'51-APR'),
   (20411,1,'90-APP-11'),
   (20411,2,'90-APR-PF'),
   (55494,1,'90-APP-11'),
   (55494,2,'45-VA'),
   (42162,1,'70-M-VA-SM-DZ'),
   (49977,1,'26-8x10'),
   (49977,2,'45-CO'),
   (49977,3,'45-CH'),
   (49977,4,'20-BC-L-10'),
   (89638,1,'70-M-CH-DZ'),
   (89638,2,'70-M-CH-DZ'),
   (89638,3,'50-ALM'),
   (89638,4,'90-CH-PF'),
   (73438,1,'90-CHR-11'),
   (73438,2,'50-APR'),
   (96258,1,'90-CHR-11'),
   (96258,2,'90-BLK-PF'),
   (96258,3,'24-8x10'),
   (96258,4,'70-LEM'),
   (19258,1,'90-CHR-11'),
   (12800,1,'70-LEM'),
   (12800,2,'20-CA-7.5'),
   (12800,3,'90-ALM-I'),
   (12800,4,'90-APR-PF'),
   (81368,1,'50-CHS'),
   (81368,2,'90-CH-PF'),
   (70655,1,'26-8x10'),
   (70655,2,'70-TU'),
   (70655,3,'90-ALM-I'),
   (70655,4,'45-CO'),
   (19002,1,'26-8x10'),
   (19002,2,'25-STR-9'),
   (31874,1,'70-MAR'),
   (31874,2,'70-MAR'),
   (31874,3,'90-LEM-11'),
   (72207,1,'70-MAR'),
   (72207,2,'20-CA-7.5'),
   (65091,1,'51-APR'),
   (42833,1,'90-CHR-11'),
   (42833,2,'70-W'),
   (42833,3,'51-BC'),
   (72949,1,'51-APR'),
   (72949,2,'70-LEM'),
   (72949,3,'90-BLK-PF'),
   (72949,4,'51-BLU'),
   (72949,5,'70-W'),
   (46248,1,'70-M-CH-DZ'),
   (38849,1,'45-VA'),
   (38849,2,'70-M-VA-SM-DZ'),
   (38849,3,'46-11'),
   (38849,4,'51-ATW'),
   (38849,5,'50-APR'),
   (86861,1,'20-BC-L-10'),
   (86861,2,'50-CHS'),
   (86861,3,'70-GON'),
   (86861,4,'51-BLU'),
   (32701,1,'90-BLK-PF'),
   (32701,2,'50-APR'),
   (32701,3,'20-CA-7.5'),
   (89182,1,'51-APR'),
   (89182,2,'51-APP'),
   (89182,3,'70-LEM'),
   (89182,4,'50-ALM'),
   (89182,5,'45-CH'),
   (68753,1,'70-R'),
   (68753,2,'46-11'),
   (68753,3,'51-BLU'),
   (68753,4,'70-W'),
   (68753,5,'51-BC'),
   (39217,1,'90-ALM-I'),
   (39217,2,'51-ATW'),
   (39217,3,'45-CH'),
   (39217,4,'90-BLK-PF'),
   (96531,1,'24-8x10'),
   (96531,2,'50-APP'),
   (96531,3,'70-GA'),
   (96531,4,'50-CHS'),
   (53922,1,'70-M-VA-SM-DZ'),
   (53922,2,'46-11'),
   (53922,3,'20-BC-L-10'),
   (53922,4,'70-GON'),
   (64477,1,'70-TU'),
   (64477,2,'90-PEC-11'),
   (64477,3,'90-BLK-PF'),
   (64477,4,'51-ATW'),
   (64477,5,'20-CA-7.5'),
   (99058,1,'50-CHS'),
   (99058,2,'90-BLU-11'),
   (99058,3,'51-BLU'),
   (99058,4,'45-CH'),
   (99058,5,'90-CHR-11'),
   (77032,1,'50-CH'),
   (77032,2,'46-11'),
   (77032,3,'50-ALM'),
   (77032,4,'70-MAR'),
   (15286,1,'70-MAR'),
   (15286,2,'50-APP'),
   (15286,3,'90-APR-PF'),
   (59774,1,'51-BLU'),
   (59774,2,'70-GA'),
   (59774,3,'90-ALM-I'),
   (35073,1,'90-CHR-11'),
   (35073,2,'70-GON'),
   (34910,1,'51-APP'),
   (34910,2,'24-8x10'),
   (34910,3,'90-PEC-11'),
   (34910,4,'51-BC'),
   (17685,1,'20-BC-L-10'),
   (17685,2,'50-APP'),
   (17685,3,'51-ATW'),
   (17685,4,'70-MAR'),
   (45062,1,'50-CHS'),
   (45062,2,'20-CA-7.5'),
   (39109,1,'90-APIE-10'),
   (39109,2,'90-APP-11'),
   (37063,1,'70-TU'),
   (37063,2,'90-APP-11'),
   (37063,3,'70-W'),
   (18567,1,'70-LEM'),
   (18567,2,'90-APR-PF'),
   (37586,1,'70-TU'),
   (62707,1,'70-R'),
   (62707,2,'90-CHR-11'),
   (62707,3,'20-BC-L-10'),
   (62707,4,'90-APR-PF'),
   (28117,1,'90-CH-PF'),
   (28117,2,'50-APP'),
   (28117,3,'25-STR-9'),
   (64574,1,'51-ATW'),
   (64574,2,'70-TU'),
   (64574,3,'70-W'),
   (40305,1,'20-CA-7.5'),
   (40305,2,'70-GA'),
   (33060,1,'45-CO'),
   (33060,2,'46-11'),
   (33060,3,'90-BLK-PF'),
   (12396,1,'90-BER-11'),
   (12396,2,'70-M-VA-SM-DZ'),
   (12396,3,'51-BC'),
   (12396,4,'90-APR-PF'),
   (12396,5,'20-CA-7.5'),
   (43103,1,'70-M-CH-DZ'),
   (39575,1,'70-M-CH-DZ'),
   (70162,1,'46-11'),
   (70162,2,'70-M-CH-DZ'),
   (70162,3,'50-APR'),
   (70162,4,'70-MAR'),
   (23034,1,'70-M-CH-DZ'),
   (23034,2,'90-APR-PF'),
   (79296,1,'90-PEC-11'),
   (79296,2,'50-APR'),
   (79296,3,'90-ALM-I'),
   (79296,4,'51-BC'),
   (79296,5,'90-PEC-11'),
   (74741,1,'90-APP-11'),
   (74741,2,'51-APP'),
   (74741,3,'70-MAR'),
   (98806,1,'26-8x10'),
   (98806,2,'50-APR'),
   (98806,3,'90-APIE-10'),
   (98806,4,'51-APP'),
   (43752,1,'90-BLU-11'),
   (47353,1,'90-APR-PF'),
   (47353,2,'90-APIE-10'),
   (47353,3,'70-TU'),
   (47353,4,'90-BLK-PF'),
   (39829,1,'20-BC-L-10'),
   (87454,1,'90-APIE-10'),
   (87454,2,'50-APP'),
   (76663,1,'25-STR-9'),
   (76663,2,'90-APP-11'),
   (85492,1,'70-M-CH-DZ'),
   (85492,2,'25-STR-9'),
   (85492,3,'90-BLU-11'),
   (85492,4,'70-M-CH-DZ'),
   (48647,1,'51-BC'),
   (48647,2,'90-APIE-10'),
   (48647,3,'90-CHR-11'),
   (61008,1,'20-CA-7.5'),
   (61008,2,'90-APP-11'),
   (96402,1,'50-ALM'),
   (96402,2,'20-CA-7.5'),
   (96402,3,'90-APP-11'),
   (35904,1,'46-11'),
   (35904,2,'90-APR-PF'),
   (49845,1,'90-BLK-PF'),
   (49845,2,'70-LEM'),
   (49845,3,'50-CH'),
   (49845,4,'90-PEC-11'),
   (46014,1,'51-ATW'),
   (46014,2,'90-APR-PF'),
   (46014,3,'45-VA'),
   (46014,4,'90-CH-PF'),
   (46014,5,'90-BLK-PF'),
   (46876,1,'70-TU'),
   (46876,2,'51-APP'),
   (34579,1,'24-8x10'),
   (34579,2,'70-GA'),
   (34579,3,'70-TU'),
   (34579,4,'26-8x10'),
   (17729,1,'51-ATW'),
   (17729,2,'50-APP'),
   (17729,3,'90-BLU-11'),
   (17729,4,'90-CH-PF'),
   (17729,5,'20-CA-7.5'),
   (74952,1,'45-VA'),
   (74952,2,'90-APP-11'),
   (74952,3,'90-BER-11'),
   (61948,1,'70-MAR'),
   (61948,2,'70-GON'),
   (61948,3,'45-CH'),
   (61948,4,'24-8x10'),
   (41064,1,'70-R'),
   (41064,2,'90-APR-PF'),
   (41064,3,'51-APP'),
   (17947,1,'50-APP'),
   (20913,1,'90-LEM-11'),
   (20913,2,'70-M-CH-DZ'),
   (20913,3,'70-LEM'),
   (95514,1,'45-CH'),
   (95514,2,'46-11'),
   (95514,3,'70-MAR'),
   (95514,4,'51-APP'),
   (24829,1,'20-CA-7.5'),
   (44590,1,'90-BLU-11'),
   (44590,2,'24-8x10'),
   (44590,3,'90-BLU-11'),
   (44590,4,'45-CH'),
   (44590,5,'90-PEC-11'),
   (65165,1,'24-8x10'),
   (65165,2,'90-ALM-I'),
   (65165,3,'70-R'),
   (65165,4,'45-CO'),
   (89588,1,'90-BLK-PF'),
   (53240,1,'25-STR-9'),
   (53240,2,'51-ATW'),
   (46674,1,'51-BC'),
   (67946,1,'90-PEC-11'),
   (67946,2,'90-APR-PF'),
   (67946,3,'90-APR-PF'),
   (67946,4,'90-LEM-11'),
   (31233,1,'70-M-VA-SM-DZ'),
   (31233,2,'50-APR'),
   (31233,3,'50-CHS'),
   (31233,4,'51-BC'),
   (15904,1,'90-CH-PF'),
   (17488,1,'50-APP'),
   (97097,1,'70-MAR'),
   (50512,1,'90-APP-11'),
   (11548,1,'45-CO'),
   (11548,2,'90-APIE-10'),
   (29908,1,'45-VA'),
   (29908,2,'51-ATW'),
   (29908,3,'25-STR-9'),
   (29908,4,'70-GA'),
   (29908,5,'90-CH-PF'),
   (20127,1,'90-BER-11'),
   (20127,2,'70-M-CH-DZ'),
   (41963,1,'50-ALM'),
   (41963,2,'90-CH-PF'),
   (16532,1,'50-APP'),
   (16532,2,'70-MAR'),
   (16532,3,'70-TU'),
   (16532,4,'24-8x10'),
   (34378,1,'90-CHR-11'),
   (34378,2,'45-VA');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `HAVING` clause is incorrect, and in addition you should only be selecting the receipt number and total price sum.

```sql
SELECT r.receipt_number, 
       SUM(p.price) AS total_price
FROM item_list i
LEFT JOIN receipts r
    ON r.receipt_number = i.receipt
LEFT JOIN customers c
    ON c.id = r.customer_id
LEFT JOIN products p
    ON i.item = p.id
GROUP BY r.receipt_number
HAVING SUM(food = 'Twist') > 0 AND total_price > 25;
```